# packagist / composer - Assign a version number

Tags: composer-php, packagist

I have people using my pacakgist library.

I want to make sure that their composer.json version requirement stated as "dev-master" will not get updated when they run `composer update`... as I have changed the underlying architecture of the package.

How do I assign a new versioning to my new update? so that they have to explicitly say I want v1.01
I currently have the composer.json as:

```
{
    "name": ...,
    "type": "library",
    "description": ...,
    "keywords": ...
    "homepage": ...,
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        ...
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["Models/"]
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The composer documentation recommends [specifying the version](https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md#specifying-the-version) using a VCS tag. With git this looks like

```
git tag -a 1.0.0 -m 'Your tag message'
```

This will tag the `HEAD` of your current branch with the version `1.0.0`. Then do

```
git push --tags
```

Once your package gets crawled again, the version should be available on packagist.

Comment: thanks bro!!! In my Source tree, I added a tag to the push... It comes through perfect now... I've had to communicate to everyone to remove the dev-master versioning and use the specific version they wanted.

Spot on!